# Merge two JSON into one

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am trying to join two JSONs into one but I can't. I have tried to transform them into String with stringify, concatenate them, and redo JSON with parse ... But it doesn't work.

This is my code (ordersByCustomerId returns a JSON object):

```
fetchMyOrders: (dispatch) => {
dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_CART_PENDING });

WooWorker.ordersByCustomerId(11, 40, 1)
  .then((response) => {

    var data = response;
    
    WooWorker.ordersByCustomerId(154, 40, 1).then((response) => {

      // here "data" should be the union of the two "response" then dispatch it

      dispatch({
        type: types.FETCH_MY_ORDER,
        data,
      });
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => { });
}
```

[ordersByCustomerId returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFOii.png) and I want to join two of the same in one.

Regards.

Edit:

So, if I have two JSONs like this, how could I merge them?

```
[{
"id": 1523,
"parent_id": 0,
"number": "1523",
"order_key": "wc_order_",
"created_via": "rest-api",
"version": "4.0.0",
"status": "processing",
"currency": "EUR",
"date_created": "2020-09-03T10:24:44",
"date_created_gmt": "2020-09-03T08:24:44",
"date_modified": "2020-09-03T10:24:45",
"date_modified_gmt": "2020-09-03T08:24:45",
"discount_total": "0.00",
"discount_tax": "0.00",
"shipping_total": "0.00",
"shipping_tax": "0.00",
"cart_tax": "26.33",
"total": "151.72",
"total_tax": "26.33",
"prices_include_tax": true,
"customer_id": 11,
"customer_ip_address": "",
"customer_user_agent": "",
"customer_note": "",
"billing": {
    "first_name": "name",
    "last_name": "last name",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "address",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "M",
    "postcode": "12345",
    "country": "ES",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "phone": "(34) 123123123"
},
"shipping": {
    "first_name": "first name",
    "last_name": "last name",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "address",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "state",
    "postcode": "12345",
    "country": ""
},
"payment_method": "cod",
"payment_method_title": "cod",
"transaction_id": "",
"date_paid": null,
"date_paid_gmt": null,
"date_completed": null,
"date_completed_gmt": null,
"cart_hash": "",
"meta_data": [

],
"line_items": [{
    "id": 469,
    "name": "test product",
    "product_id": 1197,
    "variation_id": 0,
    "quantity": 4,
    "tax_class": "",
    "subtotal": "125.39",
    "subtotal_tax": "26.33",
    "total": "125.39",
    "total_tax": "26.33",
    "taxes": [{
        "id": 3,
        "total": "26.33157",
        "subtotal": "26.33157"
    }],
    "meta_data": [

    ],
    "sku": "1234",
    "price": 31.3471075
}],
"tax_lines": [{
    "id": 471,
    "rate_code": "ES-IVA (CLIENTE FINAL)-1",
    "rate_id": 3,
    "label": "IVA (cliente final)",
    "compound": false,
    "tax_total": "26.33",
    "shipping_tax_total": "0.00",
    "rate_percent": 21,
    "meta_data": [

    ]
}],
"shipping_lines": [{
    "id": 470,
    "method_title": "Envío gratuito",
    "method_id": "free_shipping",
    "instance_id": "2",
    "total": "0.00",
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "taxes": [{
        "id": 3,
        "total": "0",
        "subtotal": ""
    }],
    "meta_data": [

    ]
}],
"fee_lines": [

],
"coupon_lines": [

],
"refunds": [

],
"currency_symbol": "€",
"_links": {
    "self": [{
        "href": ""
    }],
    "collection": [{
        "href": ""
    }],
    "customer": [{
        "href": ""
    }]
}
}]
```

Comment: JSON !== javascript object, JSON is a textual notation for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a string, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're actually dealing with JavaScript objects rather than JSON. This can be a bit confusing in JavaScript. You can kind of treat them in a similar way as they're easy to move between the two representations. The important thing as Krzysztof Krzeszewski mentioned in the comments is that JSON is a text format for data exchange.

The following is valid JSON:

```
{"key": "val"}
```

It also happens to be a valid JavaScript object as well. As a result when sending JSON over a HTTP request we will often transform the response into a JavaScript object to make it easy to work with on the frontend (or backend if you're using nodejs).

In this case it looks like that's being done for you, so you've actually got two JavaScript objects you wish to merge together. This can be done with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). For example:

```
let objOne = { keyOne: "val1" };
let objTwo = { keyTwo: "val2" };

let result = {};
Object.assigns(result, objOne, objTwo);

console.log(result);
// { keyOne: "val1", keyTwo: "val2" }
```

This takes a target object, and then multiple source objects and assigns the properties to the target object. It does this in the order you hand the targets to the function, thism eans if objTwo had a key called "keyOne" with a value of "val3" you'd end up with the following:

```
{ keyOne: "val3", keyTwo: "val2" }
```

It's useful to note that this isn't a "deep" merge. It will only do the top level properties. If you want to do a deep merge you'll either need to loop through the relevant object, or look at using a function from a library such as [the merge function from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#merge).

Comment: Hi Elliot, thanks for the explanation. I think I understand it a little better ... But I am new to JavaScript and I get a bit lost ... I have edited the main post with a JSON example that I get ...

Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Hi @pmj, I think my suggestion would work, although you probably want a deep merge using something like lodash as I suggest at the end. Be aware, your two JSON objects are both inside an array, so you'll want to pull them out of the array and do the merge (or iterate through the arrays and create a new array of merged objects).